# Constraint Layout

Tags: layout, constraints

I am not been able to use list view in android studio version 2.3 in constraint layout. Everytime I placed list view and it shows error that MATCH_PARENT is not supported in constraintlayout. How to figure out this issue

Answer (score 1):

Match parent is an invalid value for layout width or height in constraint layout. Constraint layout doesn't support march parent instead use match constraint or 0dp.

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#adjust-the-view-size